# Почему при GET-запросе через HTTP-client из Laravel теряется сессия?

Tags: php, laravel, http, сессия

Мне нужно отправить пользователя разрешить доступ к данным аккаунта в сервисе Strava.

Запускаю проект на локальном сервере. Даю пользователю ссылку на разрешение доступа. В случае если он не авторизован в сервисе, то Strava отправит его на страницу авторизации, а после авторизации на страницу разрешения доступа к данным и после разрешения доступа вернет его на главную страницу моего сайта.

Хочу сделать тоже самое, но без ссылки, а через HTTP-client Laravel'а. Отправляю GET-запрос с такими же параметрами как в ссылке. Strava так же перебрасывает пользователя авторизовываться, но после авторизации его перебрасывает по адресу "localhost:3000/session" с ошибкой 404, вместо того, чтобы отправить его разрешать доступ.
Я думаю, что при GET-запросе в отличии от перехода по ссылке теряется сессия, но как это происходит и как это исправить (и так ли это вообще) я не знаю.

Объясните, кто понимает, пожалуйста)

Comment: может куки не сохранил?

Comment: А я вообще ничего с ними делал. Я хочу понять почему при переходе по ссылке все норм, а при GET-запросе вот такая штука

Comment: "при переходе по ссылке" - имеешь в виду переход по ссылке в браузере?

Comment: Да. Я ставлю ссылку на своем сайте к Strava и если через неё доступ разрешают, то все норм

Comment: моя твоя не понимает. Что значит ты ставишь ссылку на своем сайте к страва?

Comment: На главной странице есть ссылка "Разрешить доступ", когда по ней кликают, то перебрасывает пользователя на авторизацию/разрешение в Strava

Comment: ты даже толком объяснить не можешь. Вкратце: авторизация в аккаунте Стравы скорее всего хранится в куках, ты эти куки при http-запросе не отправляешь, поэтому сервер отправляет тебя на урл авторизации.

Comment: Просто через HTTP запросы это не сделаете. Почитайте про [OAuth 2.0](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) потоки (authorization flows) и что происходит на самом деле позади в браузере.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov браузер, значит, сделает это через хттп запросы, а пхп нет?

Comment: @teran дело в том что под капотом браузер может делать не один, а несколько разных запросов, которые нужно выполнять как часть authorization workflow, в то время как в браузере они могут выглядеть иначе (визуально). Нужно смотреть ВСЕ запросы в консоли разработчика используя Preserve request log чтобы увидеть их порядок и копировать для CURL.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov нужно, да.